# Error in generating UnitTestsJUnitReport.xml in Junit-> XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, mstest

I have been facing issue from some days, I have a jenkins server and configured to use MSTest.exe for my unit test execution in ASP.net Application. This is weird as this comes for a particular SVN link. Every other SVN source code is executing well.

Below is the log of console:

TestResults\UnitTestReport.trx D:\Sonar\Tools\mstest-to-junit.xsl -o TestResults\UnitTestsJUnitReport.xml

Error occurred while executing stylesheet 'D:\Sonar\Tools\mstest-to-junit.xsl'.

Code:   0x8007000e
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/147526/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command

Comment: My server is **Windows server** _not win 7_